# How to open records with right click from list view

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, list-view, record, view

i have this this list view made with LWC but i want to open these records with right click - > open in a new tab

[image]

i want someting like this :

[image]

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: If this is all custom code, you probably should provide an icon, like the [LDS utility icon's](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/icons/#utility) `new_window`, as part of that LWC that does the opening of the record in a new window directly.

Answer (score 0):

In order to open a link in a new tab by right-clicking, the link must be embedded in an anchor `(<a>)` tag with a valid `href` attribute. Without an href attribute, the browser does not know where to navigate to when the link is clicked, and it will not be possible to open the link in a new tab.

As you can see in the yellow underlined part is the href attribute value and the name is embedded with `<a>` tag
[image]